# VideoView in Android is not playing video correctly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, singleton, android-videoview

I am having a strange issue playing a VideoView. I have done my best to simplify the code as much as possible. Below are 4 classes: A, MirrorActivity, Replay, and MyTask. Assume the following occurs in this order:

1. **A** is created.
2. **MirrorActivity**() is created.
3. Inside **MirrorActivity**()'s onCreate(), that instance calls **A**'s **setMirrorActivity**() to allow **A** to have a reference to it.
4. **A**'s **doThis**() method is called, which executes mirrorActivity.**playVideo**().
5. playVideo() is executed.
6. **Replay's** **executeVideo()** is called.
7. **MyTask** is executed.

For some strange reason, when the above is executed, the video does not play. However, when the **myButton** ImageButton is pressed inside **MirrorActivity**, it plays the video on command. Both of these seem to be doing the same thing by calling **MirrorActivity's** **playVideo**(). Do you know why the above does not execute?

**A**

```
public class A{
private static final A instance = new A();
private MirrorActivity mirrorActivity;

public static A getInstance()   {
    return instance;
}

public void setMirrorActivity(MirrorActivity mirrorActivity) {
    this.mirrorActivity = mirrorActivity;
}

public void doThis(String url){
    mirrorActivity.playVideo(String url);
}
```

}

**MirrorActivity**

```
public class MirrorActivity extends Activity {
public static String VIDEO_URL = "example.mp4";
public VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overlay_gradient);

    // Set Mirror Activity
    A.getInstance().setMirrorActivity(this);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.mirrorVideoView);
    MyTask vTask = new MyTask(mVideoView);

    ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            MirrorActivity.this.playVideo(MirrorActivity.VIDEO_URL);
        }
    });
}

public void playVideo(String videoURL)
{
    MyTask mt = new MyTask(mVideoView);
    Replay.executeVideo(MirrorActivity.VIDEO_URL, 
              this, 
              mVideoView, 
              mt);
}
```

}

**Replay**

```
public class Replay{
public static void executeVideo(String uri, Activity activity, VideoView vid, MyTask mt) 
{
    vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(activity););
    vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    mt.execute();
}
```

}

**MyTask**

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    private VideoView video;
    private int duration = 0;           // in milliseconds

    public MyTask(VideoView vid)    {
        video = vid;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)   {
        video.start();
        video.requestFocus();

        video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                duration = video.getDuration();
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are calling `execute` method to start `MyTask` `AsyncTask` Task?

Comment: Also in `doInBackground` to are trying to access `video` which is UI element which is only accessed from Main UI Thread

Comment: Inside the class Replay's function executeVideo(), it calls mt.execute(). "mt" is the name of the MyTask object.

Comment: Also in `doInBackground` to are trying to access `video` which is UI element which is only accessed from Main UI Thread

Comment: but you are not calling `executeVideo` method in `MirrorActivity` ? probably `Replay.playVideo` should be `Replay.executeVideo` ??

Comment: When pressing the imageButton in MirrorActivity, it seems to play ok. The onClickListener() for imageButton calls MirrorActivity.this.playVideo

Comment: this problem seems strange. Is it because A is singleton? Or does this have something to do with an outside class attempting to play a UI object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69367/discussion-between-android-user-and--k).

Comment: after changing `MyTask` task  is executing or not ?

Comment: Only when imageButton is pressed, the video can be played on demand. But when A.doThis() is called, it does not play the video in the VideoView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg. I believe I found the solution. I'm sorry to those who were investigating, but here is what I did to get it to work both ways. Pressing imageButton and calling A.doThis() will be able to play the video now.

I modified **MirrorActivity**'s **playVideo()** function to use the following:

```
public void playVideo(final String videoURL)
{
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             MyTask mt = new MyTask(mVideoView);
             Replay.executeVideo(videoURL, 
                  MirrorActivity.this, 
                  mVideoView, 
                  mt);
        }
    });

    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mainHandler.post(runnable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think  UI element cannot access in doInBackground . And also start() after every declaration.

Try this method too.

```
private MediaController ctlr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overlay_gradient);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
// Set Mirror Activity
   A.getInstance().setMirrorActivity(this);

   mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.mirrorVideoView);

       Uri uri=Uri.parse(videourl or video path);
        mVideoView .setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView .setVideoPath(videourl);

        ctlr=new MediaController(this);
        ctlr.setAnchorView(video);
        ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
        mVideoView .setMediaController(ctlr);
        mVideoView .requestFocus();
        mVideoView .start();
}
```

Comment: It's strange, when imageButton is pressed, it seems to work on demand. But when it comes from A.doThis() it does not play on demand

Comment: @android-user for testing can you comment that imageButton  code and give direct image path in setVideoURI()

Comment: @android-user Can run my code  from uri to start() in playVideo(String videoURL)